# Drupal: empty CCK Text Area are shown with tag <br />

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm using several CCK Text Area in my content page. The fields are optional, but if I don't fill them, I see them on the page anyway, and the content is 
 ..

```
i.e.
FieldName: <br />
```

I would like to make them disappear instead..

I found out the problem is that CCKEditor add a 
 even if I've never typed in that window. How can I disable this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as is advised in this post: [Hide empty CCK fields from view](http://www.tejasa.com/node/127)

> ```
> // hide empty fields from display
> if (!$items[0]['view']) return;
> ```
>
> Put this at top of field.tpl.php,
>   which should be copied to your theme
>   folder as per CCK theming
>   documentation.

Comment: well the field is actually not empty.. there is <br /> tag in it

Comment: There is already the if condition in content-field.tpl.php <?php if (!$field_empty) : ?> I've removed the "!" and indeed all fields disappear. The problem is that the field contains <br /> tag so they are not empty.

Comment: I've solved with <?php if (trim($items[0]['view']) == '&lt;br /&gt;') : ?> in field-content.php in CCK/Themes